# Cannot telnet to port from Azure VM

Tags: ssh, azure, telnet

I have an Azure VM setup and I have a program that SSH's out from that VM to port 7022 on my supplier's server.

Sometimes I am unable to connect to this port and this can last for up to 30 minutes or longer.  The app needs to be constantly connected 247 so this is a big problem.  The problem is intermittent.

To debug I have tried to telnet to the port, and when the problem is occurring this fails (Could not open connection to the host, on port 7022: Connect failed).  If I try to telnet to my supplier from several different machines on different networks it works.

1. A VM restart does not always fix the problem
2. Stopping and starting the VM in azure portal sometimes works but other times does not
3. I am able to view the website on the supplier server at port 80 from the VM

This seems to be a problem in Azure network - does anyone know of any steps I can take to try and isolate where the problem is happening or anything I can try in order to fix it?  Currently it seems the only option is to open a ticket with Azure and pay for their support service.

Comment: When it fails, have you tried ssh'ing from the vm manually to see what the error is? If so... please edit your question with the error seen (e.g. is it a dns resolution issue?).

Comment: You can also snapshot this vm and see if deploying a new one to a different network will stabilize the connection.

Comment: David - it's not DNS - I am able to telnet to port 80 at the same address (and view the website there).

Comment: We need more information. Is this a "Classic" VM that lives inside a Cloud Services? Or are you using Resource Manager? Do you have a Load Balancer in front of the VM? Also, how often does it happen that your connection breaks?

Comment: Qualcuno - this is your normal VM in Azure which I have configured through azure.portal.com - I'm not using Resource Manager.  The connection breaks intermittently - it does not happen on any kind of schedule.  Sometimes the connection is working fine for 12 hours, other times it may only last 30 minutes.  I would say on average it happens every couple of hours.  I am not using a Load Balancer

Comment: Do you disconnect from your VM after establishing a Telnet connection? Or leave it inactive?

Comment: proteus - yes I do disconnect the remote desktop session and leave it running